# Passing linked list from array by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, linked-list

My problem is that when trying to add to linked lists within an array it would seem to not work and I'm almost totally ignorant as to why this is. First I declare the object `move` as seen below:

```
struct move {
    move(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {
        this->startX = startX;
        this->startY = startY;
        this->endX = endX;
        this->endY = endY;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
    move()
    {
        next = nullptr;
        this->startX = -1;
    }
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int endX;
    int endY;
    move* next;
};
```

I then declare 2 arrays, one which contains 100 linked lists of the `move`object and another which contains pointers to elements in each of the linked lists in the first array. As seen below:

```
move possibleMoves[100];
move * endOfLists[100];
```

I then initialise these arrays as seen below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    possibleMoves[i] = move();
    endOfLists[i] = &possibleMoves[i];
}
```

Moving onto the function itself which adds to one of the linked lists within the `possibleMoves` array I prototype it as such:

```
void listAdd(move * list, move * object, int width);
```

I call it as such:

```
if (possibleMoves[0].startX == -1) {
    possibleMoves[0] = *(new move(x, y, x + xOffset, y + yOffset));
}else {
    listAdd(endOfLists[width], new move(x, y, x + xOffset, y + yOffset), width);
}
```

And the function is declared as such:

```
void listAdd(move * list, move * object, int width) {
    int count = 0;
    while (list->next != nullptr){
        count++;
        list = (*list).next;
    }
    std::cout << "\nCount: " << count << std::endl;
    list->next = object;
    endOfLists[width] = list->next;
}
```

Count always outputs as '0'.
Here is a link to all the code (https://pastebin.com/E5g58N6L) it's not pretty. The `listAdd` procedure is called on lines 188, 197 and 444. Here is the MCVE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>

    struct move {
        move(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
        {
            this->startX = startX;
            this->startY = startY;
            this->endX = endX;
            this->endY = endY;
            this->next = nullptr;
        }
        move()
        {
            next = nullptr;
            this->startX = -1;
        }
        int startX;
        int startY;
        int endX;
        int endY;
        move* next;
    };
void listAdd(move * list, move * object, int width);
move possibleMoves[100];
move * endOfLists[100];

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xOffset = 1;
    int yOffset = 1;
    int width = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        possibleMoves[i] = move();
        endOfLists[i] = &possibleMoves[i];
    }
    if (possibleMoves[0].startX == -1) {
        possibleMoves[0] = *(new move(x, y, x + xOffset, y + yOffset));
    }else {
        listAdd(endOfLists[width], new move(x, y, x + xOffset, y + yOffset), width);
    }

void listAdd(move * list, move * object, int width) {
    int count = 0;
    while (list->next != nullptr) 
    {
        count++;
        list = (*list).next; //Go down the list until it reaches an item with nothing next.
    }

    std::cout << "\nCount: " << count << std::endl;
    list->next = object;
    endOfLists[width] = list->next;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, the first line of your initialization loop, `possibleMoves[i] = move();`, is pointless. That constructor was already called for all the instances within that array.

Comment: We where just testing to make sure. (Thanks for the confirmation though, we are questioning everything we know right now)

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using to call `listAdd`? the shortest main you can write to test it.

Comment: I added a pastebin of the whole code, but I have already checked 'x', 'y' , 'yOffset',  'xOffset' and 'width'. I'm almost certain these parameters are properly set.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @kabanus is requesting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which could be useful for you finding the issue yourself as well as help anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: Just added it sorry.

Answer (score 1):

NM the full code. You don't tell us what the initial `width` is, but assuming it's valid (that is `-1<width<100`), it doesn't matter. Look at what happens here (end of add function):

```
list->next = object;
```

At this point `list` **is** `endOfLists[width]`. Now, you properly set the next to the new object, so far so good.

But what now?

```
endOfLists[width] = list->next;
```

So the "head" pointer, saved in the global (why?) is bypassing what it originally pointed to (who has a proper `next`!) and points directly to a descendant, the new object with NULL next.  I'm guessing this wasn't what you want:

1. Leaking memory 0 - at first static allocation, but this can quickly be dynamic if you call this function the way you did a lot.
2. The head pointer is still, at the end of the function, an object with NULL next. A new one indeed, but the next is still NULL - so the next call will perform the same actions.

Basically you're swapping the head pointers, while leaking memories. You want to either:

1. Set the object next first: `object->next=endOfLists[width]`, and set the second line to let `endOfLists[width]=object`, kind of reversing the list.
2. Delete the second line, and leave the original head.

Also:

1. I can't see a good reason for globals
2. Why is the add function not a move method?
3. You need to make sure you `delete` all those `new` objects.

**EDIT**

I saw your addition - the first call **will always return 0**, since all initial objects have NULL nexts, even if you fix your code. You need two calls to the same index (`width`) at least twice to start testing this.

**Graphical addendum**

At the beginning we have 100 objects, stored in an array, all looking like this:

```
head->list->NULL
```

`list` here is the object pointed to by `endOfLists` at some index, and we call that pointer `head`. Now, we want to add the new object. We enter the addition function, with the first argument `endOfLists[width]`, so this will be our `list` argument in the function itself.

We immediately skip the while (since our next is already NULL). Getting to the first line above, we now connect our head to the new object:

```
list->object->NULL
```

So in the array we have:

```
head->list->object->NULL
```

Again, `head` is the pointer stored in `endOfLists[width]`. Now we tell `endOfLists[width]` to swap the head to a different one, setting it equal to `list->next`, which is object. So how does our memory look like?

```
head->object->NULL
list->^
```

Both `head` (the array cell) and `list` point to object, and nothing points to `list`. There we go leaking. Next time we call the function with the updated cell, we will repeat the process, leaking object:

```
head->     object2->NULL
list->object->^
```

and so forth.

Comment: I updated the post so that it wont always return 0 and that width is declared, but considering the rest of your post could you please clarify some of the terminology as I'm relatively new to C++.